# Disable connection validation when using tomcat connection pool

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, tomcat, amazon-athena

Im using tomcat connection pool with athena database, and i would like to disable requests validation because It provide lot of latence.

for each request I get 2 extra requests like 'Select 1' and 'Select * (myRequest) limit 0'

Is it possible to disable this validation mecanism ??

Here is my application properties file content  :

```
spring.datasource.tomcat.driver-class-name=com.simba.athena.jdbc42.Driver
spring.datasource.tomcat.url=jdbc:awsathena://AwsRegion=eu-west-1;AwsCredentialsProviderClass=com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain;S3OutputLocation=s3://xxx/;
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```